# Horizontal scaling of postgres in kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, horizontal-scaling

I have the following requirements for my application to be deployed in Kubernetes Cluster.  I am trying to come up with an architecture that resembles my other microservice deployment and not complicated.

- The database server nodes should have reserved capacity
- When CPU utilization goes above 60% a new database instance should spawn
- The application and the database will reside in the same cluster
- Need to support high consistency (NOT eventual consistency)

I am thinking about having multiple replicas that will connect to the same volume (NAS in my case). The postgres instances will sit behind a service like my application microservices.  Application will connect to the service and does not need to know which Postgres instance it is talking with.  This simplifies my architecture a great deal as I don't have to worry about setting up Postgres replication.

One issue in this architecture is what happens to data if a Postgres instance goes down after a write request is received.  I can introduce a message broker with consumer acknowledgement to handle this scenario, but that has some performance implication.

A sample Postgres K8s deployment configuration is shown below.  I will need to add service etc.

What are some pitfall of this architecture? Have anyone implemented something similar?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:latest
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear to me, but it sounds like you are talking about [Shared Disk Failover](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/different-replication-solutions.html)

To answer your question, the pitfalls are:

- Your NAS is a single point of failure
- Your replicas are standby replicas, so they cannot be used to scale

I think in order to get scalability and not just fault tolerance, you would need to use replication.